# How to prevent non-drawing of previous pages in Navigator?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have run into a slight issue here:

When I push a non-fullscreen Widget into the Navigator.
The previous widgets don't get drawn at all, resulting in a black background, even though the intention is to have a simple dialog box.

How do i prevent this from happening? Or what would be an easy workaround for that?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'The Dialog Issue',

      initialRoute: '/',
      routes:{
        '/': (context)=>MyHomePage(),
        '/dialog': (context)=>Dialog(child: Text('y u do dis :( and how do i change it?'))
      }
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  //This pushes the dialog onto the navigator.
  void _navigateToDialog(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/dialog');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('The Dialog issue'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Why does this happen?',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: ()=>_navigateToDialog(context),
        tooltip: 'do the stuff',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show Dialog on that home screen?

Comment: The issue is that you have a dialog as a main widget of your route. Usually you don't want that, you want to just show dialog inside the home route, which will overlay it. Check out this link -> https://coflutter.com/flutter/how-to-show-dialog-in-flutter/ specifically `_showMaterialDialog` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show dialog on the new screen, then use following in `routes`

```
'/dialog': (context) => Scaffold(
              body: AlertDialog(
                title: Text("My dialog"),
                content: Text("This is body"),
                actions: <Widget>[FlatButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), child: Text("Dismiss"))],
              ),
            ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

If you want to show `Dialog` on the home screen itself, use this:

```
void _navigateToDialog(context) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text("My dialog"),
        content: Text("This is body"),
        actions: <Widget>[FlatButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), child: Text("Dismiss"))],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: oh. I see! thanks!  
So the issue is that the Navigator just wont draw the previous thing after the transition has completed. (which is reasonable, because that would be a waste of resources).

However since the ShowDialog function doesnt change the current route,other stuff will be rendered under it. Exactly what i was looking for.